# Enterprise architect BPMN, connecting data object with message flow

Tags: associations, enterprise-architect, bpmn

I'm creating a bussines process diagram in Enterprise Architect 8, using BPMN.

How to connect Data Object with Message Flow by association?

I can't link association to message flow.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure what the question is, but one tip will be, try to use the toolbox connectors (instead of quicklinker) in such situations.
I've put up a quick mock up of connecting two data objects, a) with dataassociation, b) with messageflow, also shown example connecting data object and message with a) dataassociation b)messageflow.

I can't comment if these are syntactically correct, but can do it using the toolbox

[image: Sample BPMN 2.0]